# Tensorflow is not using/seeing my GPU! (on windows)

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

After an update of my tensorflow version, I was not able to use my GPU for eg NN training. Tensorflow was not seeing and not using my GPU, even though CUDA drivers were updated, correctly installed and I could see my GPU using Nvidia's tool nvidia-smi.exe. My system runs Window 10 and Anaconda.

After a lot of experimentation and contradictory information on the web, even from official sites such as Tensorflow, I was finally able to solve the problem and I thought to publish the solution here to save the torture from other that may face that problem.

Background info: From Tensorflow version 2.11 and upwards there is no (native) GPU support on Windows. That means that if you want your Tensorflow to see and use your GPU, you need to install Tensorflow version 2.10. According to the documentation, TF v2.10+ comes with gpu capabilities but the reality is that in many cases the GPU is not seen and you need to explicitly install the gpu-Tensorflow. Tensorflow v.2.10 is compatible with Python v.3.9-3.10.

Solution: Make a new environment via anaconda with Python v.3.9-3.10 and install tensorflow v.2.10. Then open anaconda command prompt on that environment and run "pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.10.0". To confirm that your GPU is now visible/usable by TF, create a python script with the following code and run it. You should now get "Num GPUs Available = 1". Congrats!

import tensorflow as tf
print(f'TF version: {tf.**version**}')

print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)

gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')

if gpus:
# Extract the GPU indices from the device names
gpu_indices = [int(gpu.name.split(':')[-1]) for gpu in gpus]
print("GPU Indices:", gpu_indices)
else:
print("No GPUs available in your system.")

Comment: There does not seem to be a question here. Also the support for GPUs on Windows for TensorFlow is very clearly documented in the installation guide: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native